# Overlapping Rounded Rectangles causes error in FPDF

Tags: fpdf

I am creating a PDF using the script 35 version of the Rounded rectangle function (Author: Christophe Prugnaud) and it works fine.

However, I require a filled rounded rectangle to be drawn inside an outline rounded rectangle and this causes an error e.g.

```
$this->pdf->RoundedRect($this->myleftmargin, $this->currenty, $this->mywidth, $totalheight, 8, '1234', 'D');
$this->pdf->RoundedRect($this->myleftmargin+2, $this->currenty+2, $this->mywidth-4, $totalheight-4, 8, '1234', 'DF');
```

In investigating the problem I find that if the top and left edges move in, but the right and bottom do not, there is no problem.

```
$this->pdf->RoundedRect($this->myleftmargin, $this->currenty, $this->mywidth, $totalheight, 8, '1234', 'D');
$this->pdf->RoundedRect($this->myleftmargin+2, $this->currenty+2, $this->mywidth-2, $totalheight-2, 8, '1234', 'DF');
```

Is this solvable?

=====

**Addendum**: This may not be the problem I thought it was, but it is still a problem. Running the code via Insomnia appears to return a PDF without problems - for either of the two sets of code above. BUT using the same URL via an Axios call (in Vue) causes an error in the first case but not in the second.

=====

Oliver (below), fairly, asked what the error is. Unfortunately I am not getting back anything useful for this. From the php error log I know that the problem is with the call ... $this->pdf->Output('a.pdf','I'); ... which create the error that a header has already been sent - but there is no other error before this in the log to know where that header is coming from. Logically the header must come from a error but (as you can see from the code) the difference in the working and failing code is just the value of a number.

Comment: *"this causes an error"* Are we supposed to guess which one?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I don't know why the code that worked, worked ... I now have a generic solution. The problem was that the Yii2 code that the PDF code was part of was trying to return a header from the controller. So rather than...

```
$this->pdf->Output('I');
```

which returned a PDF to Insomnia, used...

```
return Yii::$app->response->sendContentAsFile($this->pdf->Output('S'), 'a.pdf');
```

which returned the data in a form that the axios call could then use to download.